# Out of memory in XCode, but not in Instruments

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory, xcode-instruments

My app is running out of memory. In XCode's memory report I can see the memory usage rise on the device to a little bit above 500Mb before it is shut down.

When profiled in Instruments (either with the allocations tool or the leaks tool) this does not happen. The process runs up to about 100Mb and balances out as it runs the memory intense portion of the task. The app does not crash when run in Instruments.

What would cause the discrepancy?

The intense process that runs is utilizing a UIWebView to determine the length of a number of pages of content. The web view is in the background and loads a page. On completion of the load it calculates the size and loads the next page until all pages have their length calculated.

Since I have been unable to get the same memory issues to occur in Instruments, I added logging to init and dealloc methods on all of the major parts and can confirm those are being allocated and released as expected.

After that, I tried assuming that allocation and deallocation was happening properly, but that I was just allocating faster than the system could reallocate memory. I tried stopping the process early before memory ran out to see if the memory usage would drop. XCode's memory report does report a small drop, but not by a significant amount -- even after letting it sit for a few minutes.

My next step is to try to simplify the process until the problem is eliminated.

Has anyone else come across something like this where an app in Instruments does something completely different than not in Instruments or have any explanation for what might cause that?

Comment: Try use `@autoreleasepool` more frequently.

Comment: I would look at the two schemes and make sure the settings are the same. It's possible that the profiler is using a non-debug configuration and "run" is using debug configuration. I'd also pay special attention to using zombies in the latter, and that can take up memory keeping track of all of the deallocated objects. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDialog.html

Comment: @Rob Thank you, the zombies setting turned out to be the problem. I had checked the configurations between the profiler and "run" before, but missed the zombies setting. If you submit your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at the two schemes and make sure the settings are the same. It's possible that the profiler is using a non-debug configuration and "Run" is using debug configuration.

I'd pay special attention to the "Enable Zombie Objects" in the "[Diagnostics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html)" tab of the "Run" configuration, as that can take up memory keeping track of all of the deallocated objects. Zombies are a wonderful diagnostic tool, but you want to turn that off in order to ensure you reclaim all of the memory associated with the deallocated objects.

For information on getting to the scheme configuration, see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDialog.html.